# How to pass Array list to soap Web Service in Android?

Tags: android, arrays, sql-server, list, soap

I have to insert sqlite's data to SQL server.First store all data in sqlite database and then clicking a button the entire data should be inserted in SQL server. My problem is, first row is getting inserted in all rows. 
For example, if I inserted three different rows in Sqlite,but the three rows have same first row values in Sql server.

I'm using array list in this one,I don't know how to pass those array list in soap web service.

```
 push.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ArrayList<Details>  lst=new ArrayList<Details>();

        Database db=new Database(MainActivity.this);
        SQLiteDatabase sb=db.getReadableDatabase();

        Details det=new Details();
        Cursor cus=sb.rawQuery("select * from Auction",null); 
        cus.moveToFirst();

        SoapObject request=new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);

        for(int i=0;i<cus.getCount();i++)
        {
           det.Boatnum= cus.getString(0).toString();
           det. Buyername=cus.getString(1).toString();
           det. amount=     cus.getString(2).toString();

           lst.add(det);  //Array list values

           request.addProperty("Boatnum",det.Boatnum);
           request.addProperty("Buyername",det.Buyername);
           request.addProperty("amount",det.amount);

           envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
           envelope.dotNet=true;
           envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

           httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);

           try 
           {
              serviceCall();
           } 

           catch (Exception exception) {
           }    

           cus.moveToNext();
        }
    }

 });
```

Comment: why don't you send data in json format to server with a single request. Use Gson library for both client and server side to serialisation  and deserialisation data. About repeating records Log your request body/data and check on server.

Comment: my client side they created a soap url only..so that i did this

Comment: Ok. But i guess you can send whole(3 records) data at once.

Comment: ya...stored it in sqllite and then send all at a time....could you please find out what's the problem...I have to deploy in a week...please help

Comment: First let me know you are receiving the records on server which mobile sent. If yes then using (ClientSide) Gson library convert all records data to json format then set it to request body and receive the same on server.